# Some problems with SharedPreferences Boolean

Tags: java, android, boolean, sharedpreferences

I had three class, menu.class, level1.class, level2.class.

I had the following `main.xml` data

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/f1"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/button1" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/f2lock"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:src="@drawable/levellocked" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/f2"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/button2"
    android:visibility="gone" />
```

I has the following `main.class` data

```
f1 =(Button)findViewById(R.id.f1);      
f1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v){
        Intent i =new Intent(getApplicationContext(), level1.class);
        startActivity(i);            
    }             
}); 
f2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.f2)
f2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v){
        Intent i =new Intent(getApplicationContext(), level2.class);
        startActivity(i);            
    }             
});
```

The condition of f2 button is GONE, so in `level1.class`

```
if(answer.equalsIgnoreCase("8"))
    SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("preferences", MODE_PRIVATE);
boolean levelTwoUnlocked = preferences.getBoolean("f2");

if(levelTwoUnlocked){
    f2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    f2lock.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
    else {
    f2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    f2lock.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

It's mean f2 button `setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)` but I got this error in `boolean levelTwoUnlocked = preferences.getBoolean("f2");`

> The method getBoolean(String, boolean) in the type SharedPreferences
>   is not applicable for the arguments (String)

UPDATED.

i had changed the code like this

```
if(answer.equalsIgnoreCase("8"))
    SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("preferences", MODE_PRIVATE);
    boolean levelTwoUnlocked = preferences.getBoolean("f2", false);

if(levelTwoUnlocked){
    f2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    f2lock.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
    else {
    f2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    f2lock.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

but the game was force close, did the placement of the code in the wrong class? because i put the code above in `level1.class` not in `menu.class`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the android documentation.

```
public abstract boolean getBoolean (String key, boolean defValue)
```

Retrieve a boolean value from the preferences.

**Parameters**

*key:*  The name of the preference to retrieve.

*defValue:*     Value to return if this preference does not exist.

**Returns**

Returns the preference value if it exists, or defValue. Throws ClassCastException if there is a preference with this name that is not a boolean.

**Now your problem:**

It clearly says you need to pass a default value too.

Change your call like this

```
boolean levelTwoUnlocked = preferences.getBoolean("f2", false); // or true according to your default value
```

**PS:** Please don't think I am being rude, but you should look for the documentation at least once when error clearly say method definition is not matching or in any other such case.

Comment: You should put the code in `menu.class`. You must be getting the crash because `f2` and `f2lock` is not available there.

Comment: logcat is unused bro because I had use Bluestack to test the project , avd is too slow

Comment: it still force close too in menu.class

Comment: Your original problem is solved. You should post a new question for this problem. Without logcat or complete code I can't help. In any case please post a new question.

Comment: oh sorry bro my mistake, i forgot to make f2lock finviewbyid